Why these two representations are equivalence?
Assume that $A$ is a finite dimensional real vector space and $\sigma :G\to GL(A)$ is a representation. We denote by $A^*$ the vector space dual to $A$ and consider the bilinear pairing $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle :A^*\times A\to \mathbb{R}$ by $\langle p,\alpha \rangle =p(\alpha)$. Let $\sigma^*:G\to GL(A^*)$ be dual representation of $\sigma$ defined by $\sigma^*_f (p)=p\circ \sigma_{f^{-1}}$. Also consider the action $G\times A\to A$ and $G\times A^*\to A^*$ by $f\cdot \alpha =\sigma_f (\alpha)$ and $f\cdot p=\sigma_f^* (p)$, respectively. We can easily see that $\langle f\cdot p ,f\cdot \alpha\rangle =\langle p,\alpha\rangle$. Since $A$ is finite demiensional, it is isomorphic to its dual, so there exists an isomorphism $I:A\to A^*$. I wanted to show that the presentations $\sigma$ and $\sigma^*$ are equivalence in ths case: i.e. for every $f\in G$, $I\circ \sigma_f =\sigma^*_f \circ I$ but I couldn't.
My try: Using $I$ and parining $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$, I defined a non-degenerate bilinear form $(\cdot ,\cdot ):A\times A\to \mathbb{R}$ on $A$ as follows: $(\alpha ,\beta):=\langle I(\alpha ),\beta\rangle$ for all $\alpha ,\beta \in A$. Now for every $f\in G$, we have $$\sigma^*_f \circ I(\alpha )(\beta)=\sigma^*_f (I(\alpha))(\beta)=I(\alpha )\sigma_{f^{-1}}(\beta)=I(\alpha )(f^{-1}\cdot \beta)=\langle I(\alpha),f^{-1}\cdot \beta\rangle =\langle f\cdot I(\alpha ),\beta \rangle.$$
If $f\cdot I(\alpha )=I(f\cdot \alpha )$, then we have $$=\langle I(f\cdot \alpha),\beta\rangle =I(f\cdot \alpha )(\beta)=I\sigma_f (\beta)=I\circ \sigma_f (\alpha) (\beta)$$ and we get the result.

You can't prove that $\sigma$ and $\sigma^*$ are equivalent because in general they are not.
